# база данных для Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую базу данных лучше всего использовать на хостинге Heroku.

Начала писать на Sqlite3 и потом нашла инфу, что Heroku не поддерживает ее и вообще не перезаписывает файлы...

Answer (score 1):

Я использую `ClearDB MySQL`, ее довольно просто поставить на Heroku. [Как это сделать.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb)

Также могу посоветовать `PostgreSQL`. [Документация](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql)

Исключительно **НЕ** рекомендую использовать `MariaDB`, там постоянные ошибки подключения.

Comment: спасибо большое